# Showing a function is not one-to-one near the origin

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x+2x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \text{ if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 \text{ if } x=0 \end{cases}$$

I'm trying to show this is not one-to-one near $0$.  I was given a hint to consider three sequences: $x_n=\frac{2}{(4n-1)\pi}$, $y_n=\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}$, and $z_n=\frac{2}{(4n-3)\pi}$ and evaluate them using $f$.  I'm able to evaluate them, i.e., just plug them in.  I'm not sure what to do after I have my $f(x_n), f(y_n), \text{and }  f(z_n)$.

The functions evaluated at each sequence:
$f(x_n)=\frac{2}{(4n-1)\pi}+2\left(\frac{2}{(4n-1)\pi}\right)^2\sin\left(\frac{(4n-1)\pi}{2}\right)$
$f(y_n)=\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}+2\left(\frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}\right)^2\sin\left(\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}\right)$
$f(z_n)=\frac{2}{(4n-3)\pi}+2\left(\frac{2}{(4n-3)\pi}\right)^2\sin\left(\frac{(4n-3)\pi}{2}\right)$

Comment: What are the values of $f(x_{n})$, $f(y_{n})$ and $f(z_{n})$?

Comment: I'm guessing intermediate value theorem (but I didn't compute the function values).

Comment: @TomHarris I added the sequences.

Comment: You're not done evaluating. These sines take very simple values at these points.

Comment: Note that $\sin (\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}) = \sin (2n \pi + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin (\frac{\pi}{2}) =1$, and similar for the others.

Answer (score 3):

An idea without the MVT (and BTW check your function is differentiable everywhere):

$$\left(x+2x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}\right)'=1+4x\sin\frac{1}{x}-2\cos\frac{1}{x}$$

Choosing wisely some sequences, check the above derivative changes "a lot" of sign when close to zero...

Comment: I have shown that it is differentiable everywhere.

Comment: Good for you...

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you have to use MVT.

As an "alternative" way evaluate $f'(x)=1+4x\sin(\frac1x)-2\cos(\frac1x)$ at the sequences $2x_n, ?$.

Answer (score 0):

Direct but tedious evaluation shows that for sufficiently large $n$, it holds that
$$ 0 < y_n < x_n < z_n \text{ and } f(y_n) < f(x_n), f(x_n) > f(z_n).$$
Choose $\lambda_n \in (\max\{f(y_n), f(z_n)\}, f(x_n))$. 
Since $f$ is continuous everywhere, by intermediate value theorem, there exist $\alpha_n \in (y_n, x_n)$ and $\beta_n \in (x_n, z_n)$ such that 
$$f(\alpha_n) = f(\beta_n) = \lambda_n.$$
Clearly, $\alpha_n \neq \beta_n$. Hence $f$ is not one-to-one.

The above proof doesn't rely on differentiation. In fact, I am a little confusing on how to give rigorous details by using MVT.

Comment: You just approved an edit [on this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/318953/264) that was obviously spam. [Look again at the details](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/469304). ***Be more careful when you review suggested edits***.