# Parallel System - Conditional Probability Question

Tags: probability

So, I have no idea if I'm doing this correctly. I think I am, but I haven't received much help from my teacher and the TA is very, very sick.

The question is: there's a parallel system that is functional whenever at least one component is working. Each component independently works with probability 1/2. Find the conditional probability that component 1 works given a functioning system.

Conditional Probability formula: $P(E\mid F) = P(E\ and\ F) / P(F)$

P(E) = chance of component 1 working: 1/2

P(F) = functioning system = 1 - P(system isn't functioning) = 1 - (.5)^n, where n is the amount of components the system has.

$P(E\ and\ F)/P(F) = (1/2)(1 - (.5)^n) / (1-(.5)^n) = 1/2$

Is this correct, or am I missing something important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your computation comes from not calculating $\Pr[E \cap F]$ correctly.  Events $E$ and $F$ are not independent.  If $E$ occurs, then $F$ also occurs, because if component 1 is working, then the system is functioning.  So $$\Pr[E \cap F] = \Pr[E] = 1/2.$$

If there are $n$ components in the system, then you have correctly computed $$\Pr[F] = 1 - 2^{-n}.$$  The rest should now be straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

In a parallel system, it is always true that if a single component works then the parallel system will definitely work hence the probability of the functioning system & the component 1 together merely depends on that of the component 1, thus we have

$$P(E and F) or P(F and E)=P(E)=\frac{1}{2}$$
hence, 
$$P(E|F)=\frac{P(E and F)}{P(F)}=\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}=\frac{2^{n-1}}{2^n-1}$$

Comment: You just approved an edit [on this answer of mine](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/318953/264) that was obviously spam. [Look again at the details](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/469304). ***Be more careful when you review suggested edits***.