# T/F: any number that can be written as a fraction is rational.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, rational-numbers

> Any number that can be written as a fraction is rational.

I am being asked this question, and I believe it is true but for some reason,I feel that there is a trick. However, the definition of rational numbers is similar to this hence why i believe this is true.

Any objections?

Comment: What about $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$?

Comment: $\frac{\pi}2$ is a fraction..

Comment: It is a trick.  A rational is any number that can be written as a fraction *of integers* .  All real numbers can be written as a fraction between real numbers.  21/57 is rational because 21 and 57 are integers.  $\pi/4$ is not rational because $\pi$ is not an integer.  Now some might try to say $\pi/4$ isn't a "fair" fraction.  And the are right; it isn't fair.  But technically it is a fraction.  Just not one between integers.

Comment: Any number that can be written as a fraction of elements of $\mathbb Z$ is in $\mathbb Q$, becuase the latter is the field of fractions of the former. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions

Comment: Related:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318948/are-all-integers-fractions Make sure to scroll down for the comic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rational number is a number $k$ such that

$k=\frac{a}{b}$

where both $a$ and $b$ are integers.

In other words $a,b \in\mathcal Z$

Hope this helps!

Comment: ... and $b \ne 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you take just 'a fraction' then, $x=\frac{x}1$ is a way to represent every number as a fraction. What this is getting at the fact that it matters that a rational number if 'a fraction of *two integers*' - and the above form only works in that definition when $x$ is an integer. This means that the condition that numerator and denominator are integers actually is a substantial restriction on the possible forms.