# Does a fraction that can be simplified as an integer belong to the set of integer numbers?

Tags: fractions, integers

Consider the question: $$\frac{12}{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Would you consider the above statement mathematically correct? and why?

I'm a bit on the side of calling it a true statement. However, since $\frac{12}{2}$ is equivalent to 6 but not exactly identical, I am quite skeptical.

Also, how about the case: $$\frac{12}{1} \in \mathbb{Z}$$

I checked this question [Are all integers fractions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318948/are-all-integers-fractions). it has some insight addressing a similar issue, yet some answers make it even more confusing for me.

Thank you!

Comment: If one is to be pedantic, then the rational numbers and the integers are two disjoint sets. But if your problem is not in set theory, but rather calculus, number theory, combinatorics, or almost any other mathematical field, then you shouldn't be that pedantic, because it only obfuscates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR version: Yes, if you define $\mathbb{Q}$ properly and imbed $\mathbb{Z}$ into it.

Long version:

That depends on definitions.

To understand such cases, let's discuss the formal definition of the rational field $\mathbb{Q}$.

Let $R := \{(a,b) \mid a,b, \in \mathbb{Z}, b \neq 0\}$ be the set of all fractions.
On $R$, we define a relation $\sim$ by saying
$$(a,b) \sim (c,d) : \Leftrightarrow ad = bc$$
where we evaluate the last equation over the integers (as $a,b,c,d$ are all integers).
Now one can show that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, so we can look at the equivalence classes $R/\sim$. On these classes, which I will denote by $[a,b]$, we can define an addition and a multiplication as
$$[a,b] + [c,d] := [ad + cb,bd]$$
$$[a,b] \cdot [c,d] := [ac,bd].$$

One now shows that

1. Addition and multiplication are well defined (i.e. do not depend on the representative of the equivalence class we chose).
2. $(R/\sim, +,\cdot)$ forms a field, which we will call $\mathbb{Q}$.
3. The map $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}, x \mapsto [x,1]$ is an injective ring homomorphism.

As $f$ is injective, we get that $\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to its image in $\mathbb{Q}$, and thus we can identify it.

Returning to your first question: As $(12,2)$ and $(6,1)$ are in the same equivalence class, we have that $\frac{12}{2}$ lies in the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ under $f$ - and, if you allow to identify these, in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Note that the above construction does not only work for $\mathbb{Z}$ but for many other rings. There are even similar constructions for rings that are no integral domains (in this case the map $f$ is often not injective).

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{12}{2}=6\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $\frac {12}{1}=12\in \mathbb{Z}$. As long as you can simplify the expression to an integer number the number is $\in \mathbb{Z}$.